# SQL query in 2012 works, 2005 does not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have the following query that i need help with converting it to syntax that MS SQL 2005 would understand since **FORMAT** among other things in it are not supported by that old version.

```
"SELECT " & _
     "TMP.*," & _
     "COUNT(*) OVER () AS rCount " & _
"FROM (" & _
     "SELECT venueID, " & _
         "venueName AS venueName, " & _
         "venueAddress + ', ' + venueCity + ', ' + venueState + ' ' + venueZip AS venueAddress, " & _
         "venueLatLong AS coordinates, " & _
         "FORMAT(venueEventDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US') + ' @ ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,venueTime) AS dateAndTime, " & _
         "SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, 1, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong)-1) AS Lat, " & _
         "SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong) + 1, 1000) AS Lng, " & _
         "(round(" & _
             "3959 * acos " & _
               "(" & _
                   "cos(radians('" & center_lat & "')) " & _
                   "* cos(radians(SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, 1, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong)-1))) " & _
                   "* cos(radians(SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong) + 1, 1000)) " & _
                   "- radians('" & center_lng & "')) " & _
                   "+ sin(radians('" & center_lat & "')) " & _
                   "* sin(radians(SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, 1, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong)-1)))" & _
               ")" & _
        ", 1, 1)) AS distance " & _
        "FROM meetUpMarkers) " & _
     "TMP " & _
"WHERE distance < " & radius & " " & _
"ORDER BY venueName,distance DESC;"
```

I tried to replace *FORMAT* with *CONVERT* but it still seems to be incorrect.

When i change *FORMAT* to *CONVERT* i get the error:

> Type venueEventDate is not a defined system type.

**UPDATE**

Uggg... now when I run it local i get this:

Now even when i run it local i get this error???!??! and its 2012:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

**Does this mean line 2, word 5 has the error?**

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Try replacing the whole line with just `venueEventDate as dateAndTime`.  After you get the query working, worry about how you format the date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Doing that gives me the error **Error converting data type varchar to float.**

Comment: @StealthRT, did you try convert(varchar(40),venueEventdate, 101)

Comment: @StealthRT . . . Nothing in your query would be converting that value to a float, so I don't understand the error message.

Comment: I would suggest converting the whole thing to a stored procedure instead of a pass through query. That way you can pass your parameters from the front end and let the sql side handle the rest of it. Makes debugging easier and updates are super painless. Given the complexity of the calculation this is highly likely to change and using procs also eliminates the need to redeploy the front end code to change the calculation.

Comment: Now even when i run it local i get this error???!??! and its 2012:

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
Error converting data type varchar to float.

Does this mean line 2, word 5 has the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments for [`FORMAT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) and [`CONVERT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) are in a different order.  The error message indicates you put the field name into the data type argument position.  It's:

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

vs

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

Try replacing `FORMAT(venueEventDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US')` with this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, venueEventDate, 101)`
```

Comment: Do not specify a string type without a declared length as sometimes the default is 1. `VARCHAR(30)` is fine.

Comment: @srutzky I've never experienced that.  That said, `VARCHAR(10)` is all that's necessary as style 101 is always exactly 10 characters long.

Comment: It might be when using in a column and/or local variable. There are two defaults: one is 30 and one is 1, depending on where it is used. But yes, 10 is fine.